# Raspberry Pi SD in RAID1 with a USB-Stick

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, usb-power, raid

I am using my raspi for my smart home monitoring and I don't want any system crashes because the SD card fails.
So is there a way to build a raid 1 with the SD card + an additional USB stick (or maybe 2 additional sticks with one hotspare)?

Maybe with mdadm?

Would be great because if the SD fails I have the USB stick as an backup an enough time to replace the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I use initramfs now to boot to md0 (mdadm raid).
Works for now, thanks! :-)

Comment: It would be very nice if you explain how do yo setup the RAID. I would like to do the same.

Comment: you can simply check the scripts mentioned in [this blogpost](https://siking.wordpress.com/2017/01/18/raspbian-running-the-system-from-raid/) @Ingo

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I know to prevent SD card corruption is using Raspberry in readonly mode.(You can poweroff without damage and backing it up 1 time per month)

You can use the USB stick to write data output because you cannot write on SD card in this mode.

Link here https://learn.adafruit.com/read-only-raspberry-pi/overview